# Why the sudden backlog of late answers needing review?

Tags: support, review-system

Title says it all but I need to add at least 30 characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be [my fault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267080/1438). Late answers are only enqueued if the author has no more than a certain reputation level. Today, I raised that limit from 10 to 50. My intention was to add a minimal number of reviews. But I didn't account for the backlog of late answers that would be added to each and every site on the network. (Truthfully, I misread the code.)

Now that those answers have been added to the queue, I'm not so sure it was a bad idea. After all, this queue is designed to surface potentially hidden gems. Each review task can be cleared be a single person voting, commenting, editing, flagging or even upvoting an existing comment. So far the queue on other sites has shrunk rapidly as a result. As an added benefit, this is a rare opportunity to make significant progress on the Late Answer [Reviewer badge](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/73/reviewer) if you are into that sort of thing.

Comment: I think the enqueueing of more answers into the late answers review queue was useful -- a significant percentage of them need other actions than just clicking "no action needed". Probably feeding some more posts into the first posts review queue would be beneficial as well, I guess.

Comment: I found an excellent lecture series (on video, and with notes) from a question that turned up the queue due to a poor answer -- I'm not unhappy with that!